# Incorrect image written to iOS photo album

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` to save images to the photo album of the device.

I have my images in an array and they are displayed on a `PageControl`.

A download icon on the `navigationBar` saves the image to `Photos`.

I am able to save the image to `Photos` but the image saved is incorrect i.e. the image at the particular index is not saved. This is how I am adding all images to the page-control....

```
func scrollImagesWhileViewChange() {

    for i in arrayOfURLImages {

    self.pageControl.size(forNumberOfPages: arrayOfURLImages.count)
        let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
        let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.height
        let index = arrayOfURLImages.index(of: i)
        let imageA = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(index!) * scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
        imageA.image = i
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageA)
        self.imageToDownload = imageA
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(arrayOfURLImages.count), height:self.scrollView.frame.height)
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = arrayOfURLImages.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0

}
}
```

In the section `self.imageToDownload = imageA` , I am assigning the image to a `UIImageView` variable. And this is how I am saving to 'Photos'..

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageToDownload.image!, self, #selector(MyViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)`

Here the first parameter should get the correct index. But I am not able to figure out how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click download button you need to figure out the current index of page control and then on basis of current index fetch right image from `arrayOfURLImages` and then save to photo album.

Try this-

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(arrayOfURLImages[self.pageControl.currentPage], self, #selector(MyViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Comment: Yes..that's what I am confused with...How do I pass the index also with the variable 'imageToDownload' in this part UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageToDownload.image!....